# Android - How to remove single SymbolOptions from SymbolManager in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I use the SymbolManager class to add a marker as SymbolOption on Mapbox.
This is the code I wrote to add the marker and it runs:

```
fun addMarker(marker : MapboxMarker) {
    map?.style?.let {
        it.getImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID) ?: run {
            it.addImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.marker), true)
        }
    }
    symbolManager ?: run {
        symbolManager = SymbolManager(mapView!!, map!!, map!!.style!!)
        symbolManager!!.iconAllowOverlap = true;
        symbolManager!!.textAllowOverlap = true;
    }
    symbolManager!!.create(SymbolOptions().apply {
        withLatLng(marker.latLng)
        withIconImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID)
        marker.markerOptions?.let {
            withIconColor(ColorUtils.colorToRgbaString(it.markerColor))
        }
        withIconSize(1f)
        withSymbolSortKey(10.0f)
    })
}
```

where MapboxMarker is my model with latitude, longitude and marker color

```
data class MapboxMarker(
    var latLng: LatLng,
    var markerColor: Int = Color.WHITE
)
```

Now, I need to remove a marker from map, but

```
symbolManager?.delete(symbolOption)
```

doesn't compile, it needs a Symbol object and SymbolOption is not a Symbol.

So... how can I remove a single SymbolObject?

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare a **SymbolManager**:

   ```
   private lateinit var mSymbolManager : SymbolManager
   ```
2. In your Fragment / Activity implement the interface **OnMapReadyCallback**

   ```
   class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

   override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {

           mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.SATELLITE) { style -> 

               mSymbolManager = SymbolManager(*YOUR_MAP_VIEW*, mapboxMap, style)
               mSymbolManager.iconAllowOverlap = true
               mSymbolManager.textAllowOverlap = true
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. To add a marker:

   ```
   style.addImage("NAME_OF_MARKER_IMG", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, YOUR_DRAWABLE_ICON))
   mSymbolManager.create(
                       SymbolOptions()
                           .withLatLng(LatLng(LATITUDE,  LONGITUDE))
                           .withTextAnchor(Property.TEXT_ANCHOR_TOP)
                           .withTextField("YOUR_TEXT_HERE")
                           .withIconImage("NAME_OF_MARKER_IMG")
                           .withTextColor("#COLOR") // #FFFFFF = WHITE
                   )
   ```
4. To delete all markers:

   ```
   mSymbolManager.deleteAll()
   ```
5. To delete specific marker:

   ```
   // Declare reference to that marker
   private lateinit var mSymbol: Symbol

   // During the creation save that reference
   mSymbol = mSymbolManager.create(...)

   // Use the SymbolManager to delete it
   mSymbolManager.delete(mSymbol)
   ```

A special thanks to [Aboukinane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12777571/aboukinane) for saving my life on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly creating the symbol object, but you are not storing a reference to it. You need that reference to delete it. Therefore you can solve your problem by keeping track of the symbols you create.

For that just keep the reference in a variable:

```js
val symbolManager = SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style)

symbolManager.iconAllowOverlap = true
symbolManager.iconIgnorePlacement = true

// Add symbol at specified lat/lon
val symbol = symbolManager.create(SymbolOptions()
        .withLatLng(LatLng(60.169091, 24.939876))
        .withIconImage(ICON_ID)
        .withIconSize(2.0f))
```

You now have the reference to that symbol stored inside `symbol`.

If you want to remove the symbol, you can use the reference:

```js
symbolManager.delete(symbol)
```